# Cant login with postgresql user created via ansible

Tags: postgresql, ansible

Normally, I would create create postgresql user like this.

```
sudo -u postgres psql
create user deploy_sample with password 'secret';
create database deploy_sample_production owner deploy_sample;
```

I tried to create the user through ansible script with this task

```
  - name: Create database user
    become: yes
    become_user: postgres
    postgresql_user: 
      user: user123 
      password: password123
      encrypted: yes
      state: present
```

This does create a user but i cant login using the creds.

I tried to login with this command `psql --username=user123 --password`. I get `peer authenticate failuer` error.

Comment: Try doing sudo to postgres user before using the psql command

Comment: @Raaz did you ever get this working?  I'm experiencing this problem right now.

Answer (score 1):

Ansible configuration looks correct, and may have nothing to do with the problem.

By the message we can see that it is trying to login with the **Peer authentication** method. This means that the O.S. user is being used to connect to the database instead of the provided password (see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/auth-methods.html)

Two things you should look at:

- How is your auth method configuration?

It is in the file: `{data dir}/pg_hba.conf`

It is possible that all local connections are configured to use peer (notice that are two types of local connections, one is called **local** = connection through unix socket, the other is **host  127.0.0.1/32** = using network to reach localhost).

I would change the second one to use **md5** method, this way you will be able to connect with user/pass using network, but still use peer for local connection - useful for the system user **postgres**

- Connect with the application user using network

`psql --username=user123` -> PSQL program will try to use local connections by default, meaning that the Peer authentication is used. You probably don't have the user **user123** on the system so this will fail!

`psql -h localhost --username=user123 -d <database>` -> This way you will connect to local machine using network, thus allowing to authenticate with password.